# Can't test app on Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

I have installed react-native and already been able to deploy my app using android-studio. But when I try to deploy using `react-native run-android` it gives me the following error:

```
Starting JS server...
Running /home/leo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I have successfully installed `android-sdk-tools v25.1.7`, `android-sdk-platform-tools v24.0.2` and `android-sdk-build-tools v23.0.1` using Android Sdk Manager.

I can deploy an emulator using Genymotion and I can view it using `adb devices`, it gives the following output:

```
List of devices attached
192.168.56.101:5555 device
```

What else I have to do to deploy in my android emulator using `react-native run-android`?

Answer (score 1):

1. You might check the permissions on android/gradlew.
2. It should be 755 not 644.
3. `run chmod 755 android/gradlew` inside your app root folder.
4. Then run `react-native run-android` and it should work again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your device in genymotion has lower api than your android sdk build tools, api 23, because you already add it before installing react native.
Try:

1. Add new device in genymotion
2. Select device that has api 23
3. after installing, start the device
4. re run your code.